# Get time of missed call from Skype for Business?

Tags: skype-for-business

I'm a long time user of Skype-for-not-business and am used to getting good info about missed calls.

More recently we've started using Skype for Business (out of necessity to work with clients) and when I miss a call will, it just shows the date of the call, but no time.

How can I see the time of the call?